# List Comprehension of IPWhois Module output

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ip, list-comprehension

I am trying to pull out the data from a `IPWhois` lookup and put it into a `list`. I do not know the list comprehenion behind pulling out the nested list items in `results2[7]`

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import pprint

obj = IPWhois('74.125.227.206')
results = []
results = obj.lookup_rws()
print '**********************************'
print 'PPrint Result:'
pprint.pprint(results)
print ''
print '**********************************'
results2 = results.items()

print '**********************************'
print 'After putting them into lists: '
print ''
print results2[0]
print results2[1]
print results2[2]
print results2[3]
print results2[4]
print results2[5]
print results2[6]
print results2[7]
print '**********************************'
```

Result:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python whois.py
**********************************
PPrint Result:
{'asn': '15169',
 'asn_cidr': '74.125.227.0/24',
 'asn_country_code': 'US',
 'asn_date': '2007-03-13',
 'asn_registry': 'arin',
 'nets': [{'abuse_emails': 'arin-contact@google.com',
           'address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway',
           'cidr': '74.125.0.0/16',
           'city': 'Mountain View',
           'country': 'US',
           'created': '2007-03-13T12:09:54-04:00',
           'description': 'Google Inc.',
           'handle': u'NET-74-125-0-0-1',
           'misc_emails': None,
           'name': 'GOOGLE',
           'postal_code': '94043',
           'range': u'74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255',
           'state': 'CA',
           'tech_emails': 'arin-contact@google.com',
           'updated': '2012-02-24T09:44:34-05:00'}],
 'query': '74.125.227.206',
 'raw': None}

**********************************
**********************************
After putting them into lists:

('asn_registry', 'arin')
('asn_date', '2007-03-13')
('asn_country_code', 'US')
('raw', None)
('asn_cidr', '74.125.227.0/24')
('query', '74.125.227.206')
('nets', [{'city': 'Mountain View', 'updated': '2012-02-24T09:44:34-05:00', 'han
dle': u'NET-74-125-0-0-1', 'description': 'Google Inc.', 'tech_emails': 'arin-co
ntact@google.com', 'country': 'US', 'abuse_emails': 'arin-contact@google.com', '
created': '2007-03-13T12:09:54-04:00', 'range': u'74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255',
'state': 'CA', 'postal_code': '94043', 'address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway', '
cidr': '74.125.0.0/16', 'misc_emails': None, 'name': 'GOOGLE'}])
('asn', '15169')
*********************************
```

Inteded result would be to also get the items in `results2[7]` it it's own list. There is wrench in the chain when it comes to splitting it up as their is a lead in with `('nets', [{` that I am not sure how to approach.

I have attempted this:

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import pprint

obj = IPWhois('74.125.227.206')
results = []
results = obj.lookup_rws()
print '**********************************'
print 'PPrint Result:'
pprint.pprint(results)
print ''
print '**********************************'
results2 = results.items()
results3 = results[7]
results4 = results3.items()


print '**********************************'
print 'After putting them into lists: '
print ''
print results2[0]
print results2[1]
print results2[2]
print results2[3]
print results2[4]
print results2[5]
print results2[6]
print results2[7]
print '**********************************'
print results4
```

with result of:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python whois.py
**********************************
PPrint Result:
{'asn': '15169',
 'asn_cidr': '74.125.227.0/24',
 'asn_country_code': 'US',
 'asn_date': '2007-03-13',
 'asn_registry': 'arin',
 'nets': [{'abuse_emails': 'arin-contact@google.com',
           'address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway',
           'cidr': '74.125.0.0/16',
           'city': 'Mountain View',
           'country': 'US',
           'created': '2007-03-13T12:09:54-04:00',
           'description': 'Google Inc.',
           'handle': u'NET-74-125-0-0-1',
           'misc_emails': None,
           'name': 'GOOGLE',
           'postal_code': '94043',
           'range': u'74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255',
           'state': 'CA',
           'tech_emails': 'arin-contact@google.com',
           'updated': '2012-02-24T09:44:34-05:00'}],
 'query': '74.125.227.206',
 'raw': None}

**********************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whois.py", line 13, in <module>
    results3 = results[7]
KeyError: 7
```

Comment: the list in the value of nets can have more than one items.. How would you wan it then? Can you post an example of the intended out put?

Comment: FYI, [use `lookup_rdap()` according to ARIN](https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/rws/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print things in a tuple instead of dictionary may be this will help.

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import pprint

obj = IPWhois('74.125.227.206')
results = []
results = obj.lookup_rws()
print '**********************************'
print 'PPrint Result:'
pprint.pprint(results)
print ''
print '**********************************'
results2 = results.items()

print '**********************************'
print 'After putting them into lists: \n'

for item in results2:

     if item[0] == 'nets':
        temp_result = []
        for stuff in item[1]:
            temp_result.append(item[1].items())

     else:
         temp_result = item[1]

     print temp_result

print '**********************************'
```